# Azure ADLS Gen 2 writing to blob storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm having a hard time writing to ADLS Gen 2 blob storage with c#.
Is this feature available?

I'm trying to update my code from ADLS Gen 1 to Gen 1.

This piece of code works fine with ADLS Gen 1

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run
                (   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
                    Binder binder , 
                    TraceWriter log)

    {
var container = "my_container";
var path = container + "/test.txt" ;
using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(new BlobAttribute(path)))
{
    writer.Write("Hello there !!!!!");
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages back when you try Gen 2? Is the code the same for both types?

Comment: In addition check the program interface in the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

ABFS  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver let me know the status

Answer (score 1):

As of Feb 2019 there's no .NET SDK currently available for writing files in Data Lake Gen 2 so your code wouldn't work.

Check the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues):

> There aren’t SDKs available that will work with Data Lake Storage Gen2 accounts.

For latest SDK availability please also see "Programming Interfaces" chart here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

---

At this stage your only option is to use REST API. Documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2)

Answer (score 1):

You could also programmatically invoke AzCopy v10, passing the --output-type=json flag to make its output parseable by your C# code.  That works if you're uploading from/downloading to disk and that's what Storage Explorer does. But you'd need to use REST as @mai mentioned if you are uploading from/downloading to in-memory "files" that don't exist on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to leverage the recently published (preview) version of the csharp SDK, which is documented here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet